# Remote form opens all other remote forms on the page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ujs

I have a user dashboard controller with multiple remote forms inside the same view for the user to update misc attributes:

```
class CustomerDashboardController < ApplicationController
  def settings
  end
end
```

```
//settings.html.erb
<div class="info__item">
  <p class="info-item__heading">Name: <%= link_to "Edit", "", class: "info-edit__link", id: "user-edit__name", remote: true %></p>
</div>

<div class="info__item">
  <p class="info-item__heading">Email: <%= link_to "Edit", "", class: "info-edit__link", id: "user-edit__Email", remote: true %></p>
</div>
```

The jquery ujs triggers exist in a `*.js.erb` file, with it's name matching the appropriate action/view template that the forms are contained in:

```
//customer-dashboard/settings.js.erb
$('#user-edit__name').hide().after('<%= j render("user-edit-name-form") %>');
$('#user-edit__address').hide().after('<%= j render("user-edit-address-form") %>');
```

Each of the forms renders and updates the attributes correctly,
However when clicking on a single link with `remote: true`, it renders every single form partial on the page simultaneously instead of just the single partial related to that link with unique `id: ""`

Comment: Just curious, do you have the option of rendering all of the forms with `display: none` and toggle the visibility instead of hitting a JS action to render the form?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, that does work and allows me to skip `remote: true` altogether, but I'd rather the user have the option to render only the form that they requested to edit in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By @NM Pennypacker's suggestion, I came to a solution by skipping using `remote: true` altogether and just using Javascript to toggle the visibility of the multiple form partials instead.

My javascript solution:

```
  allEditButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.info-edit__link');

  const showFormListener = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleAdjacentFormVisibility(event);
  };

  allEditButtons.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', showFormListener);
  });

  function toggleAdjacentFormVisibility(event) {
    event.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle(
      'info__is-not-visible'
    );
    event.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle(
      'info__is-visible'
    );
  }
```

The view:

```
  <div class="info__item">
      <p class="info-item__heading">Email: <%= link_to "Edit", "", class: "info-edit__link" %></p>

      <p class="info-item__info">
        <%= @user.email %>
      </p>

      <div class="info-item__form-container">
        <%= render ('user-edit-email-form') %>
   </div>

    </div>

  <div class="info__item">
      <p class="info-item__heading">Email: <%= link_to "Edit", "", class: "info-edit__link" %></p>

      <p class="info-item__info">
        <%= @user.phone %>
      </p>

      <div class="info-item__form-container">
        <%= render ('user-edit-phone-form') %>
      </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .info__is-visible {
    display: block;
  }
  .info__is-not-visible {
    display: none;
  }
```